# How can I build this query in doctrine Zend

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

I have all the models. I need to define relation in doctrine and build a query using doctrine.

Query without doctrine which works fine.

```
SELECT * FROM asset_site_link l
join assets a on l.assetID = a.id
join assetTypes t on t.id = a.assetTypeID
join assetCategories c on c.id = a.categoryID
where t.name="image" AND c.name = "static_banner"
and l.siteID = "2"
```

My First Attept is something like this, which did not work.

```
 $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('r.*')
    ->from('assetManagement_Model_asset r')
    ->leftJoin('r.assetTypeID t')
    ->leftJoin('r.categoryID c')  
    ->leftJoin('r.assetSiteLink l')                        
    ->where('r.isDeleted = 0')
    ->andWhere('t.name = ?', "image")
    ->andWhere('c.name = ?', "static_banner")
    ->andWhere ('l.siteID = ?', "2");
```

while below query is working fine (without assetSiteLink join)

```
 $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('r.*')
    ->from('assetManagement_Model_asset r')
    ->leftJoin('r.assetTypeID t')
    ->leftJoin('r.categoryID c')  
    ->where('r.isDeleted = 0')
    ->andWhere('t.name = ?', "image")
    ->andWhere('c.name = ?', "static_banner");
```

Just to tell you that Asset model has one to Many Relation with AssetSiteLink

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('r.*, l.*')
        ->from('linkManagement_Model_assetSiteLink l')
        ->leftJoin('l.assetSiteLink r')                        
        ->leftJoin('r.assetTypeID t')
        ->leftJoin('r.categoryID c')              
        ->where('r.isDeleted = 0')
        ->andWhere('t.name = ?', "image")
        ->andWhere('c.name = ?', "static_banner")
        ->andWhere('l.siteID = ?', "2")
   ;
```

Comment: I believe if you are seting up relations corectly in the base class you don't need to use join statement in query. It automatically picks the related records

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is wondering why the code that is above won't execute for them, it might be due to using the "andWhere()" function. In my version of the Zend Framework, there is no "andWhere()" function; you just call where() twice, instead.

This means that, for me, the above piece of code would need to be written like so:

```
q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('r.*, l.*')
        ->from('linkManagement_Model_assetSiteLink l')
        ->leftJoin('l.assetSiteLink r')                        
        ->leftJoin('r.assetTypeID t')
        ->leftJoin('r.categoryID c')              
        ->where('r.isDeleted = 0')
        ->where('t.name = ?', "image")
        ->where('c.name = ?', "static_banner")
        ->where('l.siteID = ?', "2")
```